# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined and loader not disappearing

Tags: javascript

I work with Brackets and currently trying to add a loading page to the website I'm working on.
I have come across a problem in which I get the following error: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined"**.
In addition, the loader is not disappearing.

Here is my code:
HTML

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
   
<body>

    <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
    <script>
var loader = document.getElementById('loader').style.display='block';

window.addEventListener ("load", function() {
    //Hide the spinner after 2 seconds
setTimeout(function(){loader.style.display = 'none';}, 2000);

});</script>
    <div class="content"> 
     Website content,,,, </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('https://lkp.dispendik.surabaya.go.id/assets/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
var loader = document.getElementById('loader').style.display='block';
```

initializes the variable `loader` with the string "block".  You have to use two separate statements:

```
var loader = document.getElementById('loader');
loader.style.display='block';
```